# trying to make update data into multiple table in CI

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to make update data into multiple tables that have some join relationship, here's my table.

#### Table1: input_pen

no_form | no_lahan | t_utama

#### Table2: lahan

no_lahan | jenis

here's my controller called **c_read**

```
function upAksi(){
    $no_form = $this->input->post('noform');
    $no_lahan = $this->input->post('nolahan');
    $t_utama = $this->input->post('tutama');
    $jenis = $this->input->post('jlahan');

    $this->m_read->upAksi($no_form, $no_lahan, $t_utama, $jenis);
    redirect('c_read');
}
```

and here's my model called **m_read**

```
function upAksi($no_form, $no_lahan, $t_utama, $jenis){
    $this->db->set('input_pen.t_utama', $t_utama);
    $this->db->set('lahan.jenis', $jenis);

    $this->db->where('input_pen.no_form', $no_form);
    $this->db->where('input_pen.no_lahan', $no_lahan);
    $this->db->update('input_pen JOIN lahan ON input_pen.no_lahan= lahan.no_lahan');
}
```

did i do wrong? that code made some error like
[image]

I already check the query in phpmyadmin, and it running well

```
UPDATE input_pen JOIN lahan ON input_pen.no_lahan = lahan.no_lahan
SET input_pen.t_utama = 'PADI', lahan.jenis = 'Lahan Rawa'
WHERE input_pen.no_form = 42 AND input_pen.no_lahan = 71
```

Comment: UPDATE usually needs a table name. Why you add `JOIN`?

Comment: did i do wrong? i already added table name, input_pen and lahan @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter active record doesn't allow to update a joined tables.

After trying the various method and searching the solution. By using the following method, you can update multiple tables using Codeigniter active record.

#### sample code:

```
$this->db->set('a.firstname', 'Pekka');
$this->db->set('a.lastname', 'Kuronen');
$this->db->set('b.companyname', 'Suomi Oy');
$this->db->set('b.companyaddress', 'Mannerheimtie 123, Helsinki Suomi');

$this->db->where('a.id', 1);
$this->db->where('a.id = b.id');
$this->db->update('table as a, table2 as b');
```

After seeing your final comment I will suggest you do it separately.

#### your Update Querys

```
//First Table Update
$this->db->set('a.t_utama', $t_utama);
$this->db->where('a.no_form',  $no_form);
$this->db->where('a.no_lahan', $no_lahan);
$this->db->update('input_pen as a');
// Second Table Update
$this->db->set('b.jenis', $jenis);
$this->db->where('b.no_lahan', $no_lahan);
$this->db->update('lahan as b');
```

And event this not help the use your working query in `$this->db->query( your query );`.

That's all i can suggest. Hope it will help.

Comment: it didn't change anything too :(

Comment: I have updated the answer please try that and reply me @Kiki

Comment: where should i put that code? first code in model and the other code in controller? am i right?

Comment: no, i have suggested both the option for the model. You should do all database related operation in models as the best practices.  @Kiki

Comment: i already tried that code too, but its just gave me some error to. 2 code that you suggested is gave some errorr to

Comment: I have tried to do as your table structure. Please try that and reply. @Kiki

Comment: i already tried, that gave some error "Table 'input_pen as a, lahan' doesnt exist"

Comment: @Kiki may be the problem is something else, so as the final effort I have added two separate query to update.  Try that and that's all I can suggest.

Comment: i have one more question, actually my table have many column. can i just use $data for all column? right now i use one variable for one column like $t_utama and $jenis

Comment: last question already answered, i didnt use db->set but use update(table, $data)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be extra backtick in the produced query added by the update-method. Try to remove the extra space to see if it helps:

```
$this->db->update('input_pen JOIN lahan ON input_pen.no_lahan=lahan.no_lahan');
```

Comment: it didn't help, nothing change

Comment: What does the error code look like after the change?

Comment: Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`no_lahan=lahan`.`no_lahan` SET `input_pen`.`t_utama` = 'PADI', `lahan`.`jenis`' at line 1

UPDATE `input_pen JOIN lahan ON` `input_pen`.`no_lahan=lahan`.`no_lahan` SET `input_pen`.`t_utama` = 'PADI', `lahan`.`jenis` = 'Lahan Rawa' WHERE `input_pen`.`no_form` = '42' AND `input_pen`.`no_lahan` = ''

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/cobaCI/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 656

Comment: Looks like the update-method treats the parameter string as a table name and escapes it accordingly.

Comment: what should i do then? sorry i'm new in this thing

Comment: You can use CI raw query and pass the SQL to the query-method: $this->db->query( $sql );